# Flash Simulated Download Showing Loader But Loader Is Skipped On Web Page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the same preloader I have used for lots of other flash projects before so I know it works but for some reason it isn't doing so here.

I have made sure all of my symbols are exported in frame 2 and the preloader loads the main class by getting it through the definition name so it is not loaded too early and the loader is on frame 1.

When I run the application in the IDE and perform a simulated download then the loader is displayed correctly once 2% of the application has been downloaded, and continues through to 100% when it shows the application.

When I run the application in a web page then it shows nothing for a few seconds and in the chrome network tab it is visibly downloading it. Once the swf is completely downloaded then the loader flashes up complete for a second and the application moves on to the main part.

When I generate a size report I get this:

`Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene

-------    -----------    -----------    -----

      1         228408         228408    Scene 1

      2       11189678       11418086     (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)`

It looks to me like the application is only displaying the first frame once it is fully loaded, or it is somehow loading the loader images after everything else, but that would be strange since it is the same project I've made 50 times before just copied and altered.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try opening the web page in other browsers? Also it can be a caching proxy issue, there are proxy servers or software that first download the entire SWF, then scan it by antivirus software, then pass its entire byteset to the browser, resulting in this behavior.